# How to split a Single Column with multiple entries into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, multiple-columns, quotation-marks

I have a csv file with entries of multiple columns in a single column with multiple quotes. When I load it in R using data.table(fread) it appears as a table with quotes. I have tried using quote=FALSE, but it is not working.

[Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3uRa.png)

[I also tried reading it using read.csv it appears as a single column with multiple entries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hrxY.png)

I also tried using print.data.frame using quote=FALSE. But it is not working either.

So I have two problems:

1. How to split this single column into multiple and
2. How to remove these quotes

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Screenshots are not helpful for sharing data. Please add data using `dput` so that it is easier to help you. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question without having reproducible data, but here is an example which may help you:

You need to use the data.table and assuming your Bev is a data.frame, you process each column with quotes with the `gsub` function like below.

```
d <- data.frame(site = c('"hello"','"vietnam"'),value= c(1,2))
d
#       site value
#1   "hello"     1
#2 "vietnam"     2
d$site <- gsub('"', '', d$site)
d
#     site value
#1   hello     1
#2 vietnam     2
```

Consider renaming your colnames, it will be easier later on to work with this dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the quote marks are a result of how you read-in the data. Try to read-in your data as .txt. That is, copy-and-paste the data from the csv-file to a txt-file and use `read.table` as well as these arguments:

```
data <-read.table("[Your path]/[File name].txt", header=T, quote="", sep="\t", fill=F, comment.char="")
```